# include xsd using lxml without include statement in the xsd itself

Tags: xml, xsd

I will start by saying I am new to xml schemas.

I am trying to load a schema.xsd file as schema(etree.XMLSchema module) which uses a type from a different xsd, let's call it other.xsd, when schema.xsd doesn't have an include statement for other.xsd. I am trying to find a way to load the other.xsd as a reference in my python script but till now without success. I don't want to change the schema.xsd and add the include statement.

I know that in a different team in my work they have a .net solution to it but I need a python one.

any suggestions?

I tried creating a catalog.xml like offered here: [lxml include relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615382/lxml-include-relative-path)
but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: your schema is invalid by default if you used a type that is declared into another schema that is not referenced. only by including or importing the schema that contains the type you will get a valid xml schema.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I changed the file and added the include statements but still get an error: References from this schema to components in the namespace '' are not allowed, since not indicated by an import statement. any ideas?

Comment: yes, an include of an extra schema requires a different target namespace. if you want to use an other xml schema file that has the same or no namespace you import a schema into it.

Comment: Thanks! this was helpful. but it seems that when I import a xsd it is only importing the first one. It resolve types that is in the first xsd I import but not in the rest. 
why is this happening and how can I resolve it?
Thank you very much

Comment: you need to add for every other file where content is used from an import statement.